# Определить направление движения мыши

Tags: javascript, графика, геометрия

Добрый Вечер. Есть div. Как можно отследить с какой стороны наводится мышь на этот div ? То есть, по событию mousemove, отследить с какой стороны наводят на этот div. С начала я думал отследить координаты мыши, учитывая текущую и прошлую точки и по ним определить направление. Но получается, что мне каким то образом нужно отследить еще и направление движения (то есть вниз/верх/вправо/влево), помимо координат. Подскажите пожалуйста, вариант решения.

Comment: разница между координатами текущей и предыдущей точек и даст Вам направление - вектор перемещения

Comment: Дело в том, что это может работать для двух направлений - то есть влево/вправо или вверх/вниз. Для всех 4 направлений такой проверки не достаточно.

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом. Для задания/описания направления в математике существует понятие - вектор. Как его найти - я Вам уже написал.

Comment: Скажите, то есть с помощью направляющего косинуса, я смогу найти направление движения вектора ?

Comment: Вот видите, Вы уже заговорили про косинус (а раньше было только "вниз/верх/вправо/влево"), значит понимаете, что курсор может двигаться под углом к осям координат. Да, сможете.

Comment: Извините, я просто в математике тупой, поэтому стараюсь понять, как именно мне поможет определение этого косинуса. Получается , что по двум точка я смогу определить координаты вектора. Затем, я смогу использовать эти координаты, что бы посчитать направляющий косинус, после чего  я не понимаю, как мне это поможет найти направление вектора.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49453/discussion-between-drylozav-and-igor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const DEG_TO_RAD = Math.PI / 180;
const RAD_TO_DEG = 180 / Math.PI;


const point = ( x = 0, y = 0 ) => ({ x, y });
const length = ( { x, y } ) => Math.sqrt( x * x + y * y );
const normalize = ( vector ) => {
    let vectorLength = length( vector );
    let { x, y } = vector;

    return point( x / vectorLength, y / vectorLength );
};
const subtract = ( a, b ) => ({ x: a.x - b.x, y: a.y - b.y });

const DIRECTIONS = {
 TOP: "top",
 RIGHT: "right",
 BOTTOM: "bottom",
 LEFT: "left"
};

const defaultBorder = `3px solid black`;
const getBorder = side => ({
 borderTop: `${ side === DIRECTIONS.TOP ? defaultBorder : '' }`,
 borderRight: `${ side === DIRECTIONS.RIGHT ? defaultBorder : '' }`,
 borderBottom: `${ side === DIRECTIONS.BOTTOM ? defaultBorder : '' }`,
 borderLeft: `${ side === DIRECTIONS.LEFT ? defaultBorder : '' }`,
})
const actionMap = {
 [ DIRECTIONS.TOP ]: element => Object.assign( element.style, getBorder( DIRECTIONS.TOP ) ),
 [ DIRECTIONS.RIGHT ]: element => Object.assign( element.style, getBorder( DIRECTIONS.RIGHT ) ),
 [ DIRECTIONS.BOTTOM ]: element => Object.assign( element.style, getBorder( DIRECTIONS.BOTTOM ) ),
 [ DIRECTIONS.LEFT ]: element => Object.assign( element.style, getBorder( DIRECTIONS.LEFT ) ),
}

let rect = document.body.querySelector('.rect');
let rectangle = rect.getBoundingClientRect();
let center = point(
 rectangle.width / 2 + rectangle.left,
 rectangle.height / 2 + rectangle.top
);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', document_mouseMoveHandler);

function document_mouseMoveHandler( { clientX, clientY } ){
 let mouse = point( clientX, clientY );
 let mc = subtract( mouse, center );
 let direction = normalize( mc );
 let angle = Math.atan2( direction.y, direction.x ) * RAD_TO_DEG;

 let type = getDirection( angle );
 let action = actionMap[ type ];

 action( rect );
}

function getDirection( angle ){
 if( angle <= -45 && angle > -130 ){
  return DIRECTIONS.TOP;
 }else if( angle > -180 && angle <= -130 || angle <= 180 && angle > 130 ){
  return DIRECTIONS.LEFT;
 }else if( angle > 45 && angle <= 130 ){
  return DIRECTIONS.BOTTOM;
 }else if( angle <= 45 && angle > -45 ){
  return DIRECTIONS.RIGHT;
 }
}
```

```css
.rect {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;

 background: tomato;

 position: absolute;

 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;

 transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Скажите, для ясности. Вы здесь через нормализованный вектор, высчитываете направляющий косинус ?

Comment: @Drylozav да, а что?

Comment: Просто хотел понять общую идею, что бы читать Ваш вариант решения. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

предложу альтернативный вариант:

Можно проверить пересекается ли каждая сторона(или отрезок) прямоугольника с отрезком, начало которого это текущая позиция курсора, а конец - центр прямоугольника, и, с каким отрезком получили пересечение с той стороны и двигается мышка

Тоесть, по сути, всё, что нужно это сделать - это корректно проверить пересечение отрезков, а остальное тривиально :)

```js
;(function() {
  let rect = document.getElementById("rect");
  let rectWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(rect).width);
  let rectHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(rect).height);  
  let rectTopLeft = {
    x: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(rect).getPropertyValue("left")),
    y: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(rect).getPropertyValue("top"))
  };  
  let rectCenter = {
    x: rectTopLeft.x + rectWidth*0.5, 
    y: rectTopLeft.y + rectHeight*0.5
  };  
  let rectSides = {
    Top: {
     p0: {x: rectTopLeft.x,             y: rectTopLeft.y}, 
        p1: {x: rectTopLeft.x + rectWidth, y: rectTopLeft.y},
    }, 
    Left: {
     p0: {x: rectTopLeft.x,             y: rectTopLeft.y},
        p1: {x: rectTopLeft.x,             y: rectTopLeft.y + rectHeight}
    },
    Right: {
     p0: {x: rectTopLeft.x + rectWidth, y: rectTopLeft.y},
        p1: {x: rectTopLeft.x + rectWidth, y: rectTopLeft.y + rectHeight}
    },    
    Bottom: {
     p0: {x: rectTopLeft.x,             y: rectTopLeft.y + rectHeight},
        p1: {x: rectTopLeft.x + rectWidth, y: rectTopLeft.y + rectHeight}
    }    
  };       
  let sides = ["Top", "Left", "Right", "Bottom"];

  function cross2d(a, b) {
    return a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x;
  }  
  
  function segmentsIntersect(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    let v1 = cross2d(
     {x: p4.x - p3.x, y: p4.y - p3.y},
        {x: p1.x - p3.x, y: p1.y - p3.y}
    );
    let v2 = cross2d(
     {x: p4.x - p3.x, y: p4.y - p3.y},
        {x: p2.x - p3.x, y: p2.y - p3.y}
    );
    let v3 = cross2d(
     {x: p2.x - p1.x, y: p2.y - p1.y},
        {x: p4.x - p1.x, y: p4.y - p1.y}
    );
    let v4 = cross2d(
     {x: p2.x - p1.x, y: p2.y - p1.y},
        {x: p3.x - p1.x, y: p3.y - p1.y}
    );
    return v1*v2 < 0 && v3*v4 < 0;
  }
  
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    let mx = e.clientX, my = e.clientY;
    
    sides.forEach(function(side) {
     if (segmentsIntersect({x: mx, y: my}, rectCenter, rectSides[side].p0, rectSides[side].p1)) {
       rect.style["border" + side] = "4px solid #f00";
      } else {
       rect.style["border" + side] = "";
      }      
    }); 
  }  
})();
```

```css
#rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #668;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Не надо никаких косинусов.
На hover событие сохраняете координаты x , y и включатель on = 1.
По move событию получаете x1 и y1 и если выключатель включён сравниваете координаты и получаете направление. Ну и выключатель в ноль, чтобы больше не пересчитывал, пока не покинете область.

Comment: Тем, кто минусует, напишите, пожалуйста, почему это не сработает, есть шанс, что я пойму.