# Разное наложение на изображение в зависимости от стороны наведения курсора

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Ломаю голову над решением задачки.
Есть разные способы сделать наложение div при наведении на изображение
[Пример на html5css](https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_css_image_overlay_slide.php).

Стоит задача сделать подобное наложение в зависимости от стороны наведения курсора - навели справа и наложение выехало справа, убрали курсор с изображения с наложением влево - наложение сложилось влево. И так же вверх - вверх, вниз - вниз.
Отслеживание направления курсора разными способами то нашел ([определить направление движения мыши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598429/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8) ), но вот все это соединить вместе, чтобы работало как задумано, не выходит :(

Подскажите плз, куда еще копать или может попадались примеры похожей реализации.

Comment: Покажите, что вы уже начали делать, на чем застопорились и что именно не получается.

Comment: https://www.kizu.ru/ru/multi-directional-hover/

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за подсказку, оказывается он называется Multi-directional hover. Нашел примерно то что надо: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Старался сделать то, что было в примере.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('card')) {
    e.target.setAttribute('data-pos', checkCur(e, e.target));
    e.target.classList.add('--hover');
    //
    e.target.querySelector('.hover .overlay').innerText = checkCur(e, e.target); // Чисто для демонстрации, можно удалить
  }
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('card')
  && e.target.classList.contains('--hover')) {
    e.target.setAttribute('data-pos', checkCur(e, e.target));
    //
    e.target.classList.remove('--hover');
    setTimeout(function() {
      e.target.removeAttribute('data-pos');
    }, 200);
  }
}, true);

function checkCur(e, el) {
    let pos = [], check = [],
      w = el.getBoundingClientRect().width,
      h = el.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      x = (e.clientX - el.getBoundingClientRect().left),
      y = (e.clientY - el.getBoundingClientRect().top);

  if(x / w > .5) {pos[0] = w - x; check[0] = 'right';}
  else {pos[0] = x; check[0] = 'left';}

  if(y / h > .5) {pos[1] = h - y; check[1] = 'bottom';}
  else {pos[1] = y; check[1] = 'top';}
  
  return check[pos[0] < pos[1] ? 0 : 1];
}
```

```css
/* https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267211 */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #999;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.card .hover {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: #09f;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card .hover .overlay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

/* --- */

.card[data-pos="left"] .hover,
.card[data-pos="right"] .hover {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width .2s linear;
}

.card[data-pos="right"] .hover {
  right: 0;
}

.card.--hover[data-pos="left"] .hover,
.card.--hover[data-pos="right"] .hover {
  width: 100%;
}

/* --- */

.card[data-pos="top"] .hover,
.card[data-pos="bottom"] .hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: height .2s linear;
}

.card[data-pos="bottom"] .hover {
  bottom: 0;
}

.card.--hover[data-pos="top"] .hover,
.card.--hover[data-pos="bottom"] .hover {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="overlay">HOVER</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="overlay">HOVER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На ховер хорошо бы поставить overflow: hidden, иногда скролл мелькает))

Comment: Вроде везде есть, да и в FF не наблюдаю ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: А вы transition где-то на 5s поставьте, увидите)